# split() as alternative to repeated subsetting in R

Tags: r, split, subset

I have the following R routine that I am slowly building on. But I am running into some computational issues that I am insure of how to get around.

```
K <- 2 # number of subarrays
N <- 100
Hstar <- 10
perms <- 10000

K1 <- c(1:8)
K2 <- c(9:10)

probs <- c(0.45, 0.45, rep(0.10/8, 8))

specs <- 1:N

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){ 
        if(i == 1){
            pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
        }
            else{
                pop[j ,, 1] <- sample(haps[K1], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[K1])
                pop[j ,, 2] <- sample(haps[K2], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[K2]) 
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to randomly assign character labels from my 'haps' variable to more than one subarray (in above example K = 2), without having to specify both K1 and K2.

I was thinking of using something like

```
split(sample(sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs), sample(1:K, size = N, replace = TRUE)
```

in place of pop[j ,, 1] and pop[j ,, 2] in the else() statement. In this way, I will not have to subset 'haps' and 'probs' in my else statement according to what labels occur in each subarray.

My plan down the road is to place my code within a function called "HAC.sim" so that I can just do

```
HAC.sim(K, N, Hstar, probs, perms = 10000)
```

But in the current implementation, users would have to go into the internal code of the function to add another pop[j ,, i] if they wanted to include more than 2 subarrays, which is not very efficient, specially if there are 10 or more subarrays.

Is split() the right function to accomplish what I need? I have tried this method, but, I get the error "Error in pop[j, specs, i]: incorrect number of subscripts on matrix." when I replace

```
pop[j ,, 1] <- sample(haps[K1], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[K1])
pop[j ,, 2] <- sample(haps[K2], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[K2])
```

with the split() code above.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: You're missing `perms` from your code

Comment: Thanks! ... I've added it. But what part of the code are you referring to?

Comment: Your code refers to the code you've posted as a reproducible example. You've added `perms`, and that takes care of the reproducibility issue.

Comment: @CPak I'm wondering if you know of a fix for my problem?